# Mysql - logging in realtime all queries

Tags: mysql, logging, process, live

I have a simple localhost website i would like to log all queries via mysql or mysql client or mysql plugin or whatever in realtime

So that i can see in realtime which queries are runned from the site

is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok at the end i resolved using:

```
SET global log_output = 'FILE';
SET global general_log_file='/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_general.log';
SET global general_log = 1;
```

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

> So that i can see in realtime which queries are runned from the site

You can run:  SHOW PROCESSLIST;
Under mysql.
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

> I have a simple localhost website i would like to log

Log all queries before run for example in log file.

Comment: but this seems rly not in realtime and also i'm unable to see the queries list with this also if i'm using the same user and password for mysql (the same of website) ... any clue?

Comment: What do You mean "realtime". You can see all queries by checking https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/processlist-table.html.

Comment: realtime = refreshing list everytime a query is launched

Comment: You can refresh table each second and present results wherever You want